# Lua: When does it call functions?

Tags: lua, love2d

Using the Love framework by the way.

Ok, so I'm looking to create a random map generation. I obviously only want it drawn once, so I tried to set up a very basic structure. Which isn't working and I can't figure out why.

```
function love.load()
    testVar = 1
end

function love.draw()
    if testVar == 1 then
        testFunction()
        love.graphics.print("Update", 20, 200)
    end

    love.graphics.print(testVar, 100, 100)
end

function testFunction()
    love.graphics.print("Success", 20, 300)
    testVar = 0
end
```

What that is doing is only printing "0", thanks to the command to print testVar up in the draw function. So it seems that it's updating the testVar value without actually running testFunction. Is this something to do with Lua?

For those unfamiliar with Love, love.draw is called every frame, love.load only initially.

Comment: "Love Framework" ? :D hearing it for the first time...

Comment: @ShashankKadne: Technically, the `o` in Love has an [umlaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29), perhaps because the makers want it to be impossible to find via Google if you don't know how to write an umlaut with your keyboard...

Comment: The window is cleared before draw is called. It is printing ``"Success"`` but you can't see it. Try printing to console.

Comment: Oh, I may have been misunderstanding draw. Thanks. I guess this means I will need to be displaying the map through the draw function.

Answer (score 2):

This code works as expected. It's just `love.draw` is called every frame (multiple times per second), so the output from the first frame is quickly overwritten by next frames. Usually you use `love.update` when you need to make changes to your state (for example, based on user input) and `love.draw` to draw that state on the screen (every frame).